# New User trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to indicate that a new profile was created, on what date and by which the user was registered (Legend: "a new profile was created", on what date and by which user was registered).

```
Delimiter // 
create trigger movi
after [] on []
for each row 
begin
insert into movimientos values(“A new profile was created”,now(),user());
end //
```

and I want to know what to write into the brackets ([]) for it to work

Comment: This is why people spent thousands of hours [writing documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html).

Comment: @tadman you can only use INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE not CREATE USER or something like that

Comment: I honestly hope you're not creating database-level users when people sign up. That's a super bad idea for a multitude of reasons, especially because MySQL's password hashing leaves a lot to be desired. Instead create a regular user table for your application.

Comment: @tadman is just a homework...

Comment: If you're learning, that's great. The important thing is to not learn the wrong way to do things. Create a `users` table in your own database and explore. You can assign any triggers you want in that context. I don't think MySQL allows you to set triggers on system tables like `mysql.user`, or that doing such a thing is a good idea.